# Select duplicate in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in postgresql with columns District and tehsil. Tehsil names are not unique and tehsil with same name belong to multiple districts. I want to find out the tehsils with same name belonging to different districts..

```
Tehsil  District

Alot    Ratlam
Alur    Hassan
Alur    Kurnool
Aluva   Ernakulam
Khanapur    Adilabad
Khanapur    Belgaum
Khanapur    Sangli
Khandaghosh Barddhaman
Khandagiri  Khordha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select Tehsil from table
group by Tehsil 
having min(District)<>max(District)
```

To know which district they belong to

```
select t1.Tehsil, t1.district from table as t1 inner join 
(
select Tehsil from table
group by Tehsil 
having min(District)<>max(District)
) as t2 on t1.Tehsil =t2.Tehsil
```

Comment: I also want to find out to which district those tehsils belong..kindly guide

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
select Tehsil from table
group by Tehsil 
having count(Tehsil)>1
```